# Extending clickable area of a standard Win32 button?

Tags: winapi, button, margin, usability

I have a button which, due to margins (and it looks better this way) is 3 pixels from the edge of the screen. I'd like it to highlight on mouse-over in this margin region, so that it can be clicked by moving the mouse to the side of the screen.

Is there any way to extend the clickable area of a standard Win32 button, such that the button believes its clickable area to be larger than its drawing area?

Comment: Short answer: No. Mouse input goes to the window underneath the mouse pointer (unless it is captured, but that requires coöperation of the window underneath the mouse pointer to not break it). You'll have to create your own window class (or subclass the standard button class), and render the button yourself. The theme API allows you to do the rendering.

Comment: This isn't going to improve usability

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Windows does/did this with the start menu button and it felt perfectly natural, you don't even notice that you missed the button. It really depends on the rest of the UI.

Comment: Windows puts the Start button on the edge of the screen. The glyph is at the center but there is no gap. Use owner draw button with no border, or something like that. Make the whole button highlight on mouse hover, and you can draw the visible border near the center.